# Wicket migration from 1.4 to 6.0 version

Tags: java, bootstrap-4, wicket

We have a java wicket 1.4 application not so large, but now we need to integrate bootstrap 4 to it. Consulting the apache wicket site, we see a integration come since wicket 6.0 version but it is not supported for older versions.

Having project time considerations, We  have two alternatives: First, migrate from 1.4 to 1.5 and then to 6.0, this to support the "native" integration, or second, to include bootstrap in the html head instead of the html generated directly from wicket.

The first one is probably the best option but could imply a great effort. The second one, is not a clean solution but could be a temporal one.

Do you know which implications or potential issues could be arise both alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to use https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap because Wicket itself doesn't provide anything special for Bootstrap. The "problem" here is this library does not provide integration with Bootstrap **4** (https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap/issues/540) because v4 is "almost ready" for about 3 years now.

I'd suggest you to use the second approach.

Updating to a newer version of Wicket would be good anyway! Ignoring the new features and the bug fixes there are several security fixes which might or might not affect your application.

Comment: I didn't realise the fact that BS4 is not "completed" yet, then, it would be useless to make the migration if we do not have a stable integration. Good point.

Comment: Don't give up so easy! :-) They just announced 4.0.0 http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2018/01/18/bootstrap-4/

Answer (score 0):

**Use the second approach - add the bootstrap.css to your html head and use bootstrap classes manually in your html.** Just use standard Wicket. Some bootstrap components like Slider, Progress Bar,  Datepicker and Modal we have implemented as components on our own.

This gives you full control and free's you from external libraries which are not updated in time, not compatible with other frameworks/versions and so on. 
We are happy with this approach and avoid this way the problem you have.

Comment: As you, @RobertNiestroj, we use a lot of our own components, then this reinforce the second approach. great!